# wp-json/ return 404, but wp-json/wp/v2/ works fine on my nginx server

Tags: nginx, rest-api

When I access my WordPress site as `www.example.com/wp-json/` I got this 404 error.

```
`{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}`
```

But the REST api return the correct json object if I use the url of `www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/`.

My permalink is setup as `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`, and here is part of my nginx configuration settings:

```
server {

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # other location directives related to php, cache, etc.

}
```

I searched on Internet and most of the problems seems to be caused by incorrect permalink setting and .htaccess (Apache), but seldom mentioned about the case related to nginx. Any idea what cause this and how to solve it?

**Update**

If I run `curl -i www.example.com/wp-json`, this is what I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 29 Jan 2017 11:58:21 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
Link: <https://example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type

{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}
```

**Latest Update (7 Mar 2017)**

With the release of WordPress 4.7.3, this bug has been fixed. The workaround `unset ($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);` no longer needed.

Comment: What are you expecting to find at `wp-json/`?

Comment: Are you using a plugin to access the `API`?

Comment: When accessing wp-json/ I was expecting the same result as wp-json/wp/v2, this was the correct behaviour on my another server running Apache. No I don't have an plugin for REST. My WordPress is 4.7, I thought it is no longer require a plugin for REST API.

Comment: It is no longer required to have a plugin, but it looks like core end points are the `v2` version. Perhaps it is not Apache vs nginx, but you used a plugin previously?

Comment: No, I never used a plugin, as mentioned on my previous msg that for the same WordPress setting running on an Apache server works without a plugin.

Comment: Were you able to work this out? I am experiencing the same problem

Comment: No I have not received any insightful comment yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be about https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39432

Symptoms look very similar and at the time of writing hasn't been released as 4.7.3. Applying the patch manually fixed the issue on my nginx setup.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This does fixed the problem, but since it involving of modifying the code in /wp-includes, I'd prefer not to change it this way. I'm currently on 4.7.2, hope this will be fixed in upcoming 4.7.3 release. In the meantime, I follow @user113522 instruction by unsetting `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

Comment: Modifying core specifically for this patch doesn't really make a difference, since the update overwriting everything will contain the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into the same issue on an nginx only (no Apache) WordPress blank install 4.7.2 site.

The base `/wp-json/` & `index.php?rest_route=/` URLs showing `rest_no_route 404`, but all the `/wp-json/wp/v2/` working just fine.

The issue turned out to be related to the `PATH_INFO` variable passed by nginx that WordPress core attempts to build the URL off of incorrectly, if it's set to anything, even an empty string.

Needs more investigating, but I was able to fix by adding a condition on those specific pages via `REQUEST_URI` by doing this for them:

```
unset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
```

Comment: Ah, thank you @user113522, I know why this happened now. WordPress really on .htaccess to handle the redirect, but in case of Nginx, Nginx does not use .htaccess, when WordPress can't find the .htaccess, it fallback to use the PATH_INFO which add an extra index.php into the url. Your solution of adding `unset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);` works but I think it is better to setup a redirect at the nginx location directive. I will test it when I have time and post it here later.

Answer (score 1):

For me, updating the permalinks to something special than the first option did the job.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me with the proposed nginx setup from wordpress.
add this to your nginx.conf

```
location /wp-json/ { # Resolves WP Gutenberg 404 issue
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

and change the 'Permalinks' settings to 'Post name'

this should work with `/wp-json` issue.
[https://wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nginx-helper/#description)

I configured a network site with the instructions given and it all seemed to work well.
Worth giving it a try!

Also, https sites must have right permalinks, just check that one as well!